# Cannot convert special characters to UTF-8

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, utf-8

One of my DB query from a legacy app is returning string in this format "0.5Â°,0.6Â°, 0.7Â°,0.8Â°, 0.9Â° and 1.0Â°"  which is not correct.  I am expecting the strings to be in format.
"0.5°, 0.75°, 1.0°, 1.5°, 1.75°, and 2.0".

I tried to convert the windows 1252 to utf-8 by doing the following:

```
 Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
            Encoding w1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
            byte[] w125bytes = w1252.GetBytes(htmlNormalized);
            byte[] utfbytes = Encoding.Convert(w1252, utf8Encoding, w125bytes);
            htmlNormalized = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utfbytes);
```

but I am still getting the same string with special characters. what am i doing wrong? and how can I fix it?

Comment: You can't reliably convert things once they've already been corrupted. What is `htmlNormalized`, and how did you get that value? Any fix to apply: is *there*, at the point you (or library code) obtain(s) a string from bytes. You mention "DB query from a legacy app", but how did you get that data into your app? If the corruption is outside of your code: your code cannot reliably fix it. You can make wild stabs, of course. It might mostly work.

Comment: htmlNormalized = 0.5Â°,0.6Â°, 0.7Â°,0.8Â°, 0.9Â° and 1.0Â°  it is the variable of type string that gets populated with query result.

Comment: `htmlNormalized = Encoding.UTF8.GetString( w125bytes);` (omit computing `utfbytes`, it does not give any sense as bytes are bytes - nothing less, nothing more…)

Comment: And by that time: it is already corrupted; I'm guessing it was stored corrupted